# python tkinter Image - creates a new one instead of replacing it

Tags: python, image, tkinter

I have built a simple weather app using this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7JoMTQgdxg0&t=1442s).
There is an error in the tutorial regarding the images of the weather condition so I tried to solve it myself.
I have succeeded with displaying the image but with every new search, instead of replacing the old one it "adds up on it".
Highly appreciate the help!
here's the relevant code:

```
    def search():
    city = city_text.get()
    weather = get_weather(city)
    if weather:
        location_lbl['text'] = '{}, {}'.format(weather[0], weather[1])
        temp_lbl['text'] = '{:.2f}°C {:.2f}°F'.format(weather[2], weather[3])
        weather_lbl['text'] = weather[5]
        img1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(
            f"C:/Users/Alon/PycharmProjects/Weather_app/weather_icons/{weather[4]}.png"))
        label = Label(image=img1)
        label.image = img1
        label['bg'] = '#ffffff'
        label.pack()
    else:
        messagebox.showerror('Error', 'Cannot find city: "{}"'.format(city))


app = Tk()
app.title("Weather app")
app.geometry('700x350')

city_text = StringVar()
city_entry = Entry(app, textvariable=city_text)
city_entry.pack()

search_btn = Button(app, text='Search weather', width=12, command=search)
search_btn.pack()

location_lbl = Label(app, text='', font=('bold', 20))
location_lbl.pack()

image = Label(app, bitmap='')
image.pack()

temp_lbl = Label(app, text='')
temp_lbl.pack()

weather_lbl = Label(app, text='')
weather_lbl.pack()
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not create new label for the weather image in each search, just update `image` label:

```py
def search():
    city = city_text.get()
    weather = get_weather(city)
    if weather:
        location_lbl['text'] = '{}, {}'.format(weather[0], weather[1])
        temp_lbl['text'] = '{:.2f}°C {:.2f}°F'.format(weather[2], weather[3])
        weather_lbl['text'] = weather[5]
        img1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=f"C:/Users/Alon/PycharmProjects/Weather_app/weather_icons/{weather[4]}.png")
        image['image'] = img1
        image.image = img1
    else:
        messagebox.showerror('Error', 'Cannot find city: "{}"'.format(city))
```

Comment: Thank you very much, did the trick! I need to learn tkinter from the start I guess..